# bash auto escaping of non-alphanumeric symbols

Tags: bash, sed

I have bash script for teamcity.It puts build variables value to file using placeholders.

```
sed -i ""
-e "s/BUNDLE_VERSION/%bundle_version%/"
-e "s/BUNDLE_ID/%bundle_id%/"
-e "s/APP_TITLE/%title%/" "%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%/info.plist"
```

%var% - replaced to value of var before run bash script by teamcity.

It doesn't work with variables which have `'`, `"`, `/` and probably other non-alphanumeric symbols. 
For example with `title = Auto Shop "SuperCar"` it crashes

> [12:22:07]sed: 1: ""s/APP_TITLE/Auto ...": invalid command code "

How to fix script to work with non-alphanumeric symbols?

Comment: Don't use sed. Use awk or perl and pass the variables in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before passing it to `sed` escape the special/meta characters like this:

```
BUNDLE_VERSION=$(echo "$BUNDLE_VERSION" | sed -r 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/\//\\\//g;s/\^/\\^/g;s/\[/\\[/g;s/'\''/'\'"\\\\"\'\''/g;s/\]/\\]/g;s/\*/\\*/g;s/\$/\\$/g;s/\./\\./g')
```

Example:

```
$ echo "^[a/b'c\d]*$." | sed -r 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/\//\\\//g;s/\^/\\^/g;s/\[/\\[/g;s/'\''/'\'"\\\\"\'\''/g;s/\]/\\]/g;s/\*/\\*/g;s/\$/\\$/g;s/\./\\./g'
\^\[a\/b'\''c\\d\]\*\$\.
```

and use single quotes while putting in variables for the main expression. Its better to use some other tool for passing variables like `awk`'s `-v` option.